# Spring data / Neo4j path length with large data sets

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have been running the following query to find relatives within a certain "distance" of a given person:

```
@Query("start person=node({0}), relatives=node:__types__(className='Person') match p=person-[:PARTNER|CHILD*]-relatives where LENGTH(p) <= 2*{1} return distinct relatives")
Set<Person> getRelatives(Person person, int distance);
```

The 2*{1} comes from one conceptual "hop" between people being represented as two nodes - one Person and one Partnership.

This has been fine so far, on test populations. Now I'm moving on to actual data, which consists of sizes from 1-10 million, and this is taking for ever (also from the data browser in the web interface).

Assuming the cost was from loading everything into `ancestors`, I rewrote the query as a test in the data browser:

```
start person=node(385716) match p=person-[:PARTNER|CHILD*1..10]-relatives where relatives.__type__! = 'Person' return distinct relatives
```

And that works fine, in fractions of a second on the same data store. But when I want to put it back into Java:

```
@Query("start person=node({0}) match p=person-[:PARTNER|CHILD*1..{1}]-relatives where relatives.__type__! = 'Person' return relatives")
Set<Person> getRelatives(Person person, int distance);
```

That won't work:

```
[...]
Nested exception is Properties on pattern elements are not allowed in MATCH.
"start person=node({0}) match p=person-[:PARTNER|CHILD*1..{1}]-relatives where relatives.__type__! = 'Neo4jPerson' return relatives"
                                         ^
```

Is there a better way of putting a path length restriction in there? I would prefer not to use a `where` as that would involve loading ALL the paths, potentially loading millions of nodes where I need only go to a depth of 10. This would presumably leave me no better off.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

---

Michael to the rescue!

My solution:

```
public Set<Person> getRelatives(final Person person, final int distance) {

    final String query = "start person=node(" + person.getId() + ") "
        + "match p=person-[:PARTNER|CHILD*1.." + 2 * distance + "]-relatives "
        + "where relatives.__type__! = '" + Person.class.getSimpleName() + "' "
        + "return distinct relatives";

    return this.query(query);

    // Where I would previously instead have called 
    // return personRepository.getRelatives(person, distance);
}

public Set<Person> query(final String q) {

    final EndResult<Person> result = this.template.query(q, MapUtil.map()).to(Neo4jPerson.class);
    final Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();

    for (final Person p : result) {
        people.add(p);
    }

    return people;
}
```

Which runs very quickly!

Comment: Don't use the id directly but a parameter, same for the class name. Otherwise you will loose query caching at runtime as it has to re-parse every query!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there :)

Your first query is a full graph scan, which effectively loads the whole database into memory and pulls all nodes through this pattern match multiple times.

So it won't be fast, also it would return huge datasets, don't know if that's what you want.

The second query looks good, the only thing is that you cannot parametrize the min-max values of variable length relationships. Due to effects to query optimization / caching.

So for right now you'd have to go with template.query() or different query methods in your repo for different max-values.